# Can not install Firebase CLI using npm

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, npm-install, firebase-tools

I first installed node and npm

```
Ahmads-MacBook-Pro:~ ahmadbazzi$ npm --version
5.6.0
Ahmads-MacBook-Pro:~ ahmadbazzi$ node --version
v8.9.4
```

Then i went to install the firebase CLI following the steps here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started. 
I first executed

```
Ahmads-MacBook-Pro:~ ahmadbazzi$ npm install -g firebase-tools
```

which gave me a whole bunch of warnings

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/ahmadbazzi/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @google-cloud/functions-emulator@1.0.0-alpha.23 (node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator):
npm WARN 404 SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Not Found: @google-cloud/functions-emulator@1.0.0-alpha.23
```

and a whole bunch of errors

```
npm ERR! path /Users/ahmadbazzi/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/ahmadbazzi/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/ahmadbazzi/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/Users/ahmadbazzi/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools\'',
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/ahmadbazzi/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools' }`
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ahmadbazzi/path to npmrc folder/_logs/2018-01-23T17_29_19_771Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Apparently the installation requires superuser privileges, which you can request with `sudo`.

Comment: If you are using Windows, run cmd as administrator, then will work fine. You will also need to change ExcutionPolicy from "Restricted" to "RemoteSigned" in order to use the Firebase command in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Try a variety of things:

1. Try repeatedly to uninstall and reinstall.  Sometimes the problem can clear itself up.

   `npm uninstall -g firebase-tools; npm install -g firebase-tools`
2. Check the specific permissions on the files in the error message.  Do you have write access to them?  If you don't, do you perhaps need to use `sudo` to write them?
3. Completely blow away the location where it's trying to install, which is apparently `/Users/ahmadbazzi/.npm-global` for you.

Comment: hello Mr. Doug, thank you so much for your comment. I tried option 1, but uninstalling have me the same error messages and installing. I will now try option 2 and 3 and update you.

Comment: same issue for me -- I found it in ~/.npm-global as you suggested:

$ ~/.npm-global/bin/firebase --version
3.18.6
$ 

My question is why?? and why isn't my path in ENV properly set?  I have installed on three other Macbooks, but this is the first time on a Mac-mini and it failed?!?  That does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, try:

```
npm i firebase --save --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using npm can cause issues like this, and it can be frustrating trying to solve them. These are permission issues.

There are two main solutions

1. Download the CLI binaries. Great because it makes the CLI globally available on your machine. The drawback is that download is slow.

I downloaded the CLI binaries globally onto my machine using this command

```
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```

I am using Linux os. The link may vary for different os. Please see the docs.

Downloading binaries might take up to 15 mins, yes, that long.

2. Download CLI into your project and avoid permissions.

use this command

```
npm i -D firebase-tools
```

The problem here is that whenever you want to use the CLI, you must launch it from your node_modules like this:

```
node_modules/.bin/firebase action
```

where the action is whatever you are trying to achieve.

I hope this helps.